# how to save file as pdf in javafxml application

Tags: java, file, pdf, save, fxml

i have a javafxml application and i have been trying to save users input as pdf but couldnt get it done

i have tried using varieties of filechooser methods but still couldnt get what i wanted

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();          
fileChooser.setInitialFileName("mine.pdf");
              //Set extension filter
              FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PDF files (*.pdf)", "*.pdf");
              fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
             System.out.println("finishing");
              //Show save file dialog
              File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);

              if(file != null){
                  SaveFile(text2, file);
              }
              System.out.println("finished");
    }
     private void SaveFile(String content, File file){
        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = null;

            fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
            fileWriter.write(content);
            fileWriter.close();
            System.out.println("done");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
//            Logger.getLogger(JavaFX_Text.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is `content` the output of some pdf library? I.e. an in-memory pdf? Or do you merely hope that calling an arbitrary file a pdf makes it a pdf? Considering that you use a `FileWriter` seems to indicate the latter.

Comment: I actually saw that on YouTube, while I was searching for answers but I think it's just a parameter that is inside the save file method, because it's going to represent the stuff  I want to save. Also I tried using the file output stream but that was just saving all the bytes in a single row and not even the break line tag i.e /n is working to break the content to another line. Pls I need help